# How to lock screen on Jquery Onclick and ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, client-side

I have a submit button with id "go" by which i am retrieving data from server side but due to data length is large it is taking large long time to load .For this reason i want to add screen locker on go button click but i dont have any idea how to do it through jquery on client side..

Please direct me to a link where i can get jquery screen locker ...

Here is my code...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#go").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#gridId").GridUnload();
                gridload();

            });
        });


        function gridload() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default2.aspx/MyMethod?fromdate=' + $("#fromdate").val() + '&todate=' + $("#todate").val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (ReportDataNew, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    //debugger;
                    gridData = JSON.parse(ReportDataNew.d);
                    //console.log(gridData);
                    //alert(gridData.length);


                    $("#gridId").jqGrid({
                        data: gridData,
                        datatype: "local",
                        height: '100%',
                        autowidth: true,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        rowNum: 50,
                        rowList: [50, 100, 200],
                        colNames: ['UserName', 'Ordinal', 'Extension', 'Trunk', 'DialDate', 'DialTime', 'Duration', 'Destination', 'Price'],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: 'username', index: 'username', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'ordinal', index: 'ordinal', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'extension', index: 'extension', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'trunk', index: 'trunk', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'dialdate', index: 'dialdate', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'dialtime', index: 'dialtime', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'destination', index: 'destination', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' }

                        ],
                        pager: '#gridpager',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        toppager: true,
                        loadtext: 'Loading...'

                    });
```

Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your screen "locked" you should add `<div class="locker"></div>` at the end of your `body` tag in html code. Then add some styling to `locker` class:

```
.locker {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /*lets make it semi-transparent */
z-index: 9999; /*because you could set some z-indexes in your code before, so lets make sure that this will be over every elements in html*/
}
```

And then your javascript code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var locker = $('.locker');
            $("#go").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    $("#gridId").GridUnload();
                    gridload();
                    canClick = false;
                    locker.css('display', 'block');
            });
        });


        function gridload() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default2.aspx/MyMethod?fromdate=' + $("#fromdate").val() + '&todate=' + $("#todate").val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (ReportDataNew, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    locker.css('display', 'none');
                    //debugger;
                    gridData = JSON.parse(ReportDataNew.d);
                    //console.log(gridData);
                    //alert(gridData.length);


                    $("#gridId").jqGrid({
                        data: gridData,
                        datatype: "local",
                        height: '100%',
                        autowidth: true,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        rowNum: 50,
                        rowList: [50, 100, 200],
                        colNames: ['UserName', 'Ordinal', 'Extension', 'Trunk', 'DialDate', 'DialTime', 'Duration', 'Destination', 'Price'],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: 'username', index: 'username', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'ordinal', index: 'ordinal', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'extension', index: 'extension', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'trunk', index: 'trunk', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'dialdate', index: 'dialdate', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'dialtime', index: 'dialtime', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'destination', index: 'destination', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' }

                        ],
                        pager: '#gridpager',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        toppager: true,
                        loadtext: 'Loading...'

                    });
```

Comment: Thanx Sir for your response but screen is not getting locked on adding above code..

Comment: what do you mean by saying "lock screen"?

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you have included the CSS file related to locker in your html page. You can also try with div ID. Here's my code.

Create a div tag with ID="fade" and place in your html page. Now, Copy paste the below code in any of 
your css file and include that file in your HTML page.

```
#fade {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ababab;
    z-index: 1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .20;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Now during your ajax call change the code to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#go").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#gridId").GridUnload();

document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
gridload();

document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';

            });
        });
```